`getopt` with atoi causes segmentation fault
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define PORT 12344

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int opt;
    int server_fd, client_fd, epoll_fd;
    int child_pid;
    int port = PORT;
    char* file = NULL;

    /* Argparse */
    static struct option long_options[] = {
        {"file", required_argument, 0, 'f'},
        {"port", optional_argument, 0, 'p'},
        {"help", no_argument, 0, 'h'},
        {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
    };


    while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, "f:p:h", long_options, NULL)) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'f':
                printf("file is: %s\n", optarg);
                break;
            case 'p':
                port = atoi(optarg);
                // since we will be listening on port > 1024 anyway, 0 is unused
                if (!port) {
                    printf("not a valid port\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                break;
            case 'h':
                printf("help message\n");
                exit(0);
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("end\n");
}

I am trying to build an application based on TCP. I want the program to take two arguments, a file parameter which specifies the configuration file, a number which is basically the port number to listen on  The oher arguments work just fine. But, whenever I try to use the --port ABC option, the program crashes with a Segmentation fault.
What am I missing here?

If you catch the crash in your debugger, does it happen where you expect it to happen? What is the value of opt and optarg at that point?

Also note that atoi is not very good when handling invalid input. For example it's not possible to distinguish between the valid input "123" and the invalid input "123abc". I recommend you use strtol instead.

Oh, and why optional_argument for the port argument? That makes no sense.

For long option format you need to use =. Either -p ABC or --port=ABC. If you use --port ABC you will get optarg == NULL causing your segfault.

@Someprogrammerdude I get the following in gdb
gef➤  run --port 12345
gef➤  x/s optarg
0x0:    <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x0>
I am not sure why it's 0

And you should handle the '?' that can be returned on invalid options.

@Gerhardh The Linux manual page say that "A long option may take a parameter, of the form --arg=param or --arg param." (emphasis mine).

@Someprogrammerdude I wasn't able to find any source for this, but that is what I observed by simply testing it using Ubuntu in WSL2. I would also expect it should work with long option without =.

So, for long format --arg=param and -a p works works, here but --arg param does not.

@Gerhardh Documentation can be wrong. Implementation never is. ;-)

@Someprogrammerdude my colleagues from test department might disagree, but we both know, you are right. :D

Did a little more digging and I found that the port should be a required parameter for the --arg param format to work :)

The port number doesn't need to be a required parameter. There is a default port defined at the top of the code. If there is no p option found, that can be used.

Apparently, making port a required parameter fixes the issue. After making the change, I can now use --port 13345.

Use the is_numeric function to check if optarg contains only digits before calling atoi; if not, print "port must be a valid positive number" and exit. This prevents segmentation faults by ensuring optarg is valid before converting it to an integer.

There's no is_numeric function in standard C. Also, atoi should not crash for invalid input, only if the pointer it's passed is invalid.

If you mean the OP should check each character with the is_digit function, then this will not help. The segfault happens because optarg is NULL.

You can create an is_numeric function from isdigit function and call with return bool values true or false:
bool is_numeric(const char *str) {
if (*str == '\0') {
return false;
}
while (*str) {
if (!isdigit((unsigned char)*str)) {
return false; // Return false
}
str++;
}
return true;
}

@Someprogrammerdude    "atoi should not crash for invalid input, only if the pointer it's passed is invalid." is reasonable (likely atoi(NULL)), yet C spec does not support should not crash as atoi((char [2]){'1', '2'}) (not a string error), atoi("") (no conversion error) and atoi("12345678901234567890") (overflow error), etc. result in undefined behavior (UB).

Your is_numeric function would also need to check for str != NULL.
